# How to set Caps Lock behavior in i3?

Tags: keyboard-layout, i3

On KDE *(and on GNOME as well)*, there was an option to swap Caps Lock and Escape key.

[image: Setting to Swap ESC and Caps Lock]

I was expecting this same setting window in i3, but I didn't find one. Is there any similar setting in i3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xmodmap` to swap Escape and Caps Lock on any DE.

First create a file with the following contents:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 0x42 = Escape
keycode 0x9 = Caps_Lock
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

Let's suppose it is saved as `swapkeys`.

Run the following command to swap the keys:

```
xmodmap swapkeys -display :0
```

assuming `$DISPLAY` is `:0`.

You can add the above line to your i3 config to execute automatically on startup.

Comment: `swapkeys` will be the path to the file we created?

Comment: @SantoshKumar yes

Comment: How do you write a comment in _swapkeys_ file? `#` doesn't work.

Comment: Comments start with `!`

Comment: Is there anything similar to keep NumLock *on* at boot time?

Comment: There's a package `numlockx` for that, but I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Also the following will do the same:

config file: ~/.config/i3/config or user defined

```
 xmodmap -e "clear lock"

 #disable caps lock switch
 xmodmap -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Escape"
 set caps_lock as escape
```

just for simple config at one place

Comment: If I add this to my i3 config I get an error about malformed variable assignment at the first line of this snippet.